# Sailsjs find where field is not set

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a project in SailsJs, using waterline with a mongodb database.
I have some fields defined, which are not required fields.
I need to search records where that field is not defined. For example:

```
{id: 10, name: "jj"}
{id: 11, name: "kk", surname: "sr"}
```

I want to search where surname is not defined. Anybody has a clue how to do this?

I have tried

```
{surname: null}
{surname: ''}
```

Nothing produces the desired result.

Comment: {surname: undefined} seems to do the trick. Can anybody confirm this is ok?

Comment: find(surname:'') will give u in which surname is blank,
while find(surname:null) and find(surname:undefined) will give you for which surname is null.This works for me!!
If you still have that issue.then plz add your model's and controller code!

Comment: surname: undefined is bringing me records where the "surname" field is not set. Null or "" brings records where the field is set but empty

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is `Model.find( {where: {surname: null } })` Check out this link to [Waterline Query language documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md#query-language-basics)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is $exists: false. It is currently not supported by waterline. You can use Model.native() to use it.

[Waterline native()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)

It returns MongoDB collection and you can use there native MongoDB operations:

[MongoDB $exists](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Complete code will look more like this

```
Model.native(function(err, collection) {    
    if (err) throw err;
    collection.find({
        surname: { $exists: false}
    }).toArray(yourCallback);
});
```